# Is MonoTouch can change UISwitch's label text?

Tags: text, xamarin.ios, label, uiswitch

As the title said, I was wonder if MonoTouch can change UISwitch's label text. Many topic talk about Object C's implements, and something about "catagory", who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [forum](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/5765-how-change-uiswitchs-text.html) discussing this topic.

From what it looks like to me, you can look at the SubViews of the UISwitch and cast them to UILabel and modify the text.  You can probably get more information in the MonoDevelop debugger to see which index to use.

Although, since these are private details about UISwitch, which Apple could change at any time and break your app--I don't know if I'd use it.  Would you be better off putting a UILabel next to your UISwitch describing its functionality more clearly?